# I don't know why these errors occur in omnet++ veins

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I install the omnet++, veins and sumo.

I connect the veins and sumo, and run the simulations. But only the veins is worked. Other files generate following errors.

I don't know why these errors occur.

How can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are using compatible versions of Veins, veins_inet, and INET. See [the changelog](http://veins.car2x.org/download/#changelog) for which versions are compatible.

Your screenshot also shows you compiling both `veins_inet` (compatible with INET 4.x) and `veins_inet3` (compatible with INET 3.x). Surely you don't want to use both in one simulation.

For an even easier solution, check out [Instant Veins](http://veins.car2x.org/documentation/instant-veins/), which already has OMNeT++, Veins, and the INET Framework installed and configured correctly, ready to run your first simulations.